# the word "oink" - usage

Tags: meaning

Please, check these two sentences. I would like to know if they sound natural.

1.

> I think I heard an oink. We must've wandered onto a farm.

2.

> Something was oinking behind the corner. It must be the neighbor's piglets.

Comment: As it is currently written, this question is a proofreading request. A good check for whether or not a question is a good fit here is that (if it is a good fit) it will not be answered with a simple "yes" or "no".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are correct usages, and they do indeed sound natural.  It's known as onomatopoeia.

My only nitpick is that you would `wander into` or `wander onto` a farm, but that's irrelevant.